# How to proxy specific request in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, puppeteer

is there a way to proxy / redirect specific urls to others?
for example when Puppeteer page goes to "mydomain.com" i'd like all calls to "mydomain.com/styles/*.css" be proxied to "localhost:8080/styles/*.css".
I don't want all request to be rediret through a proxy. but something similar to what https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii?hl=en chrome extension does.

Comment: This might help, it uses the option to view-source of a page so the css/images are not loaded.  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1913

Answer (score 2):

as @Hellonearthis linked, the soulution seems to be

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', (request) => {
  if (request.url().indexOf("mydomain.com") !== -1) {
    // simply replace with another url
    request.continue((request.url().replace("mydomain.com", "http://localhost:8080/styles"));
  }
  else {
    request.continue();
  }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

For puppeteersharp, it took me a while to figure it out.

```
page = await ChromeDriver.NewPageAsync();
await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);
page.Request += new EventHandler<RequestEventArgs>(async delegate (object o, RequestEventArgs a)
{
    if (a.Request.Url.StartsWith("mydomain.com"))
    {
        await a.Request.ContinueAsync(new Payload
        {
            Headers = a.Request.Headers,
            Method = a.Request.Method,
            PostData = a.Request.PostData != null ? a.Request.PostData.ToString() :  "",
            Url = a.Request.Url.Replace("mydomain.com", "http://localhost:8080")
        });
    }
    else
    {
        await a.Request.ContinueAsync();
    }
});
```